# got Internal Server error while running a jsp page in local tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, exception

[image: error]
while successful login reporting a error

[image: Source code]
actual source code

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as screenshots. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors Edit your post and insert the actual code  and error (it is however a good idea to supply an image to clarify something, but not alone without context).

Answer (score 0):

[Quoting the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String))

> java.lang.String getParameter(java.lang.String name)
>
> ```
> Returns the value of a request parameter as a String, or null if the parameter does not exist
> ```

As far as I can see, you don't pass a parameter to your page and therefore `getParameter` returns `null` and you try to access it without actually checking it.